# Convert simple ASP.NET WebForm to MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, repeater, webforms

I have simple asp.net page:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            rptTable.DataSource = GetDataFromDB();
            rptTable.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private DataTable GetDataFromDB()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

        table.Rows.Add(1, "HDD");
        table.Rows.Add(2, "Video");
        table.Rows.Add(3, "RAM");

        return table;
    }

    protected void rptTable_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tbName = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("tbName");
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        string name = tbName.Text;

        //Category.Save(int id, string name)
        //Rebuild Repeater
    }

}
```

and aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptTable" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptTable_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%#Eval("id")%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")%>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It works like simple grid and you are able to edit data directly in the grid.

How can I implement same logic in MVC ?
Thanks!

Comment: I need to read the data (row, text box) from the page in my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replicate the asp:Repeater functionality in an MVC application you would normally use a foreach loop with textboxes within bound to model properties.

You can however if you really want, include an asp:repeater control in an MVC app, but it's not going to work as you'd expect if it relies on postbacks.

If it's a simple read only control, you can put something like the following in your view:

```
<scipt runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        rptTable.DataSource = ViewData["yourViewDataList"];
        rptTable.DataBind();
    }
</script>
```

This assumes you've got something in the ViewData which can be databound, so to do that you'd likley need to create a controller method to build your DataTable as you've done in 'GetDataFromDB()'

I'm not going to go into the full implementation but at a high level, that's how you could use the control in MVC.

Comment: Actually I have already loop on my view that binds me a page, I need to read data from the row I changed and pressed save button

Comment: In that case you could perhaps wrap a form around each loop iteration which would submit to an action method called something like 'SaveRow'. In this method you could retrieve the values from the model fields which were submitted and process appropriately.